# stereo recording with Kinect

Tags: c#, audio, kinect

Following this standard: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ on wav files I wrote a method for the wav header, where

```
nChannels=2
```

obviously for stereo. How can I record two channels of the audio stream? Moreover is it possible to record with two specific Kinect's microphones somehow? I guess

```
 System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerInfo
```

includes information on handling specific microphones from the array but I haven't been able to figure out much yet...